# Unity The type does not have an accessible constructor

Tags: c#, unity-container

I recently started using unity and It seems to work well except for one place... I did some searching but I did not find anything that I can apply to my code.

Heres the code for register the types:

```
Container.RegisterType<IVsoCommunicator, VsoCommunicator>();
Container.RegisterType<IIpxConnection, IpxCommunicator>();
Container.RegisterType<IConsentService, ConsentService>(new InjectionFactory(p => new ConsentService(p.Resolve<IIpxConnection>(), p.Resolve<IVsoCommunicator>())));
Container.RegisterType<ITimer, ConsentStatusPoller>(new InjectionFactory(p => new ConsentStatusPoller(p.Resolve<IConsentService>())));
```

And the exception:

```
Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "UserManager.Services.ConsentStatusPoller", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.

Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type IConsentService does not have an accessible constructor.

-----------------------------------------------

At the time of the exception, the container was:

Resolving UserManager.Services.ConsentStatusPoller,(none)

Resolving parameter "consentService" of constructor UserManager.Services.ConsentStatusPoller(UserManager.Services.IConsentService consentService)

Resolving UserManager.Services.IConsentService,(none)
```

What do I do wrong here? First I thought that I had something private but that was not the case

Changed the registration to:

```
Container.RegisterType<ISettingsConfiguration, SettingsConfiguration>();
Container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
Container.RegisterType<IVsoCommunicator, VsoCommunicator>();
Container.RegisterType<IIpxConnection, IpxCommunicator>();
Container.RegisterType<IConsentService, ConsentService>();
Container.RegisterType<ITimer, ConsentStatusPoller>();
```

Consent service:

```
public interface IConsentService
{
    void GetConsentReplies();
    void GetConsentSmsUpdates();
}
public class ConsentService : IConsentService
{
    private readonly IIpxConnection _ipx;
    private readonly IVsoCommunicator _vso;

    public ConsentService(IIpxConnection ipx, IVsoCommunicator vso)
    {
        _ipx = ipx;
        _vso = vso;
    }

    public async void GetConsentReplies()
    {
    }

    private void UpdateLocationConsentSmsData(List<IncomingMessage> messages)
    {

    }

    private void SendConsentMessages(IEnumerable<IncomingMessage> messages)
    {


    }

    private void SaveIpxConsents(IEnumerable<createConsentResponse1> responses)
    {
    }

    public async void GetConsentSmsUpdates()
    {

    }

    private static void SaveConsentSmsUpdates(GetMessageStatusResponse resp)
    {

    }

}
```

Consent poller:

```
public interface ITimer
{
    void Start(int interval);
}
public class ConsentStatusPoller : ITimer
{
    private readonly IConsentService _consentService;
    readonly Timer _tmr;

    public ConsentStatusPoller(IConsentService consentService)
    {
        _consentService = consentService;
        _tmr = new Timer();
        _tmr.Elapsed += _tmr_Elapsed;
    }

    void _tmr_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        _consentService.GetConsentReplies();
        _consentService.GetConsentSmsUpdates();
    }



    public void Start(int interval)
    {
        _tmr.Interval = interval;
        _tmr.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to provide injection factory for IConsentService. All the required interfaces are already registered so defaul registration should be good and Unity will resolve them automatically.
Did you check if Consent service constructor is public or not?

Comment: I tried to change the code as showed in the question now. It did not work that way either. The Consent Service class is public and so is the other classes that are involved.

Comment: Is the error the same, now that you changed the registration? Also, can you post your IConsentService and ConsentService classes

Comment: Yes its the same error. I did not include the code in the classes as the class have 240 lines and I guess it doesnt matter. But I noticed when writing this that my first step was to create the ITimer but forgot to change the place where I resolve the ConsentStatusPoller to use ITimer instead. So now the error is the same but it says That the ITimer doesnt have a accessible constructor. The line Im talking about is "var consentPoller = IoC.Resolve<ITimer>();"

Answer (score 8):

This error looks like the container does not know that IConsentService is mapped to ConsentService. All of your registration looks correct, so my only guess would be to make sure all of your registration is being done, before your call to Resolve. Either that, or you have a call `Container.RegisterType<IConsentService>()` that is overriding your call to `Container.RegisterType<IConsentService,ConsentService>()`

Answer (score 7):

I just got the same error. In my case it was a little more obvious (and a little  more embarassing). The constructor for the class I tried to resolve was protected, and I resolved it from another assembly.

So the error message was actually very accurate...

> The type does not have an accessible constructor

I'm sure you've solved it by now, but check that the constructors are public if they should be.

Answer (score 0):

For myself, this was caused by a package mismatch.

My web project referenced one nuget packages, my service project referenced a different version.

I was getting this with IAmazonS3, which was previously part of AWSSDK but is now in AWSSDK.S3. One project referenced the old one.